# Mostrar registros si hay más de uno en un mismo mes. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero mostrar el código, nombre, sexo y fecha de nacimiento de alumnos del centro que nacieron el mismo mes, ordenados de diciembre a enero.
Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT código, nombre, sexo, fecha_nac
FROM alumnos
WHERE fecha_nac IN (SELECT fecha_nac FROM alumnos GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_nac) HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
ORDER BY MONTH(fecha_nac) DESC;
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado que espero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera es que me muestre los que hayan nacido en el mismo mes, y si en algún mes sólo ha nacido uno o ninguno que no aparezca independientemente del año o día de su nacimiento. Como por ejemplo, en el mes de diciembre no aparece nadie, ya que sólo una persona ha nacido en ese mismo mes. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Considera por favor agregar la declaración de tu tabla así como algunos datos de prueba que nos faciliten reproducir tu escenario y apoyarte con una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

- Selecciona de forma regular todas las columnas que deseas mostrar
- Como lo que te interesa es agrupar por la similitud del número de mes, entonces extraemos ese valor por medio de la función `MONTH` al momento de hacer el `ORDER BY`

**AL MOMENTO**

> Este ha sido el resultado mas cercano al que he llegado, en cuanto tenga algún avance edito y lo agrego.

Cosas que hace:

- Ordernar por mes de forma descendente
- Ordena por aquellos que nacieron en el mismo mes aunque sea año diferente

Cosas que faltan:

- Eliminar del set de resultados aquellos registros que muestran solo a 1 persona nacida por mes sin importar el año de nacimiento

Consulta

```
SELECT código, nombre, sexo, fecha_nac
FROM alumnos
GROUP BY código, nombre, sexo, fecha_nac
ORDER BY MONTH(fecha_nac) DESC;
```

Comment: He intentado ponerle un  `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`, después del `GROUP BY` de tu consulta, pero aún así no funciona. También he probado con `HAVING(fecha_nac)>1`. Eso lo que hace es buscar registros repetidos, pero en mi caso no funciona y no sé por qué. Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Haz `INNER JOIN` con tu vista de meses:

```
SELECT codigo, nombre, sexo, fecha_nac
  FROM alumnos a
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT month(fecha_nac) mes
                   FROM alumnos 
                   GROUP BY mes 
                   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
               ) m
      ON m.mes = month(a.fecha_nac)
  ORDER BY m.mes DESC
```